# Localização API Maps javaScripts

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

Tenho uma aplicação em  que retira os dados do banco de dados e adiciona no mapa,porem 
queria que exibisse apenas os lugares com distancia de até 20 km  da minha localização atual,como faço isso utilizando geolocalização?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$latitude = -XX.YYYY; //Coloque sua latitude
$longitude = -XX.YYYY;//Coloque sua longitude 
$km = 20;//Distância
$query = "
SELECT `cep`, (6371 * acos(cos(radians($latitude)) * 
                       cos(radians(`latitude`)) * 
                       cos(radians(`longitude`) - radians($longitude)) + 
                       sin(radians($latitude)) * 
                       sin(radians(`latitude`))))
AS `distancia`
FROM `tb_enderecos`
HAVING `distancia` < $km
ORDER BY `distancia` ASC
LIMIT 10;"; //Limita registros
?>
```